# Using the PL/SQL Packages

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do we determine that we should use packages instead of standalone subprograms in Oracle ? When do we really need to use PL/SQL packages? I am not asking the advantages of using packages over standalone subprograms.

I don't understand how is it the duplicate of the existing questions. As I have already mentioned that I am not asking answer for why should I use packages over standalone procedures/functions.

One of the interviewer asked me exactly the same question. He even mentioned that he is not asking the package preferences over standalone subprograms. He told me that if you are a PL/SQL developer, you should know the answer for this question. He was looking like around 12-15 Years experience guy.

I already know the answers for the duplicate questions mentioned.

Please let me know if any clarifications required.

Comment: Packages are not an Oracle specific, so the question is much more general.

Comment: OP is very specific about Oracle and PL/SQL. In title, text and tags.

Comment: @Rene: simply wanted to say to the OP that the same question could have been phrased for many DBMS, languages, ... I agree with your duplicate suggestion

Comment: Well the statement "*i am not asking answer for why should i use packages over standalone procedures/functions*" contradicts the question "*How do we determine that we should use packages instead of standalone subprograms*" - that **is** asking on why packages should be preferred over procedures/functions